# A language with id 'js' is not installed. Installed languages are: [] GraavlVM 17

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, java-17, graalvm

I upgraded my springboot application from JDK 11(graalVM) to JDK 17(graalVM) and whenever I run it, I always get `A language with id 'js' is not installed. Installed languages are: []`. It seems `PolyglotEngineImpl` doesn't have that language. What should I do to get rid of this error. In my `pom.xml`, I do not have any `graalvm` dependency

I upgraded the JDK 11 to JDK 17 and expected graalvm to run engine smoothly.

Comment: Oracle dropped JavaScript from the `ScriptEngine` system in JDK 13 (I think; maybe 14).

Comment: Is there anywork around for it?

Comment: Well you could try to use Rhino as a separate library but that'd probably be a lot of work.

Comment: The GraalVM people say they support modern JavaScript somehow, but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: GraalVM stopped shipping JS by default at some point, you need to run `gu install js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since GraalVM 22.2[1], JavaScript is no longer installed by default in GraalVM.

To install it, run:

```
$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/gu install js
```

After installing JavaScript with the `gu` tool you can use it as before in previous releases.

[1] http://www.graalvm.org/release-notes/22_2/